# Strange print behavior using Unicode symbols in Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, unicode, console

As part of my program, I am printing out "playing cards" in the console. I am using unicode characters for the card suits, so I made sure that the console uses UTF-8 encoding. However, with the unicode symbols, I am experiencing two strange issues that are a little hard to explain; see the picture attached.

1. The unicode character seems to change the font size of the text after it (In the picture, see that after a symbol, asterisks and numbers are at a smaller font size; letters are always regular size)
2. The unicode character prints as a question mark when it is directly after a number character, but will print correctly on the rest of the line after a letter character (In the picture, see stack 3 where it prints ? after 9 but prints the correct symbol from J on)

Picture of console:
[image: (Picture of console)]

(Note, I am a beginner programmer, so my code is probably not very efficient!)

```
// Creates 2 character arrays for the card's suit and rank, then puts them into a string array in a form like "Q of ♧" (queen of clubs)
String allCards[] = new String[52];
char suit[] = {'\u2667', '\u2662', '\u2664', '\u2661'};
char rank[] = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K'};
int k=0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<13; j++)
    {
        allCards[k] = rank[j] + " of " + suit[i];
        k++;
    }
}
// Puts 21 random cards into an array, cardFullStack
Random r = new Random();
String cardFullStack[] = new String[21];
for(int i=0; i<21; i++)
{
    int cardIndex = r.nextInt(52);
    cardFullStack[i] = allCards[cardIndex];
}
// Prints 3 stacks of 7 cards each, see picture attached above.
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Stack " + (i+1) + ":");
    System.out.println("******  ******  ******  ******  ******  ******  ******  ");
    System.out.println("*    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  ");
    for(int j=0; j<7; j++)
    {
        // ISSUE LINE:
        // Should get the rank and suit of the card, and print something like "* Q♧ *"
        System.out.print("* " + cardFullStack[7*i+j].charAt(0) + cardFullStack[7*i+j].charAt(5) + " *  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("*    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  *    *  ");
    System.out.println("******  ******  ******  ******  ******  ******  ******  ");
}
```

I really have no idea why this issues are occurring. This is the best I could get the cards to appear. I appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to work OK for me on macOS 10.14.6 using Eclipse 2019-09. Maybe an issue with the font you are using.

Comment: Works for me. Try DejaVu Sans Mono.

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449 and @ daxim, it seems to work with DejaVu Sans Mono! None of my computer's default monospace fonts worked, but after downloading the dejavu font, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to come from the font. I am still unsure why most of the monospace fonts I tried had the same issues, but the program worked using DejaVu Sans Mono.